# Remove Duplicates from Sorted List in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, linked-list, singly-linked-list, let

Given the head of a sorted linked list, delete all duplicates such that each element appears only once. Return the linked list sorted as well.

Input: head = [1,1,2]
Output: [1,2]

Solution:

```
    let curr=head;
    while(curr && curr.next){
        
        if(curr.val===curr.next.val){
            curr.next=curr.next.next;
        }
        else{
            curr=curr.next;
        }
    }
 return head;
```

I am trying to solve this question on leetcode and found one solution which I am not able to understand one thing, Why are we taking the `head` in `let curr`? And, If I am trying to do the same thing without taking`head` in another variable then I am getting only `[2]` as output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why are we taking the `head` in `let curr`?

For two reasons:

1. `curr` needs to be initialised to *something*, otherwise it will have an undefined value, making the `while` condition always false, so there will be no iterations and no removals happening.
2. `curr` is intended to refer to each (non-duplicate) node one after the other, so it makes sense to start with the *first* node, which is `head`.

> And, If I am trying to do the same thing without taking `head` in another variable then I am getting only [2] as output.

That could only happen when you *also* change the `return head` by `return curr`. If you do that, then you will *always* return a list that has no more than one node, because after the loop has completed, `curr` will refer to the last node in the list (if it is not empty).

In order to return all nodes in a list, you need to always return its *first* node, and that is what `head` represents.

Comment: Oh, I got it. Thank you so much for your help.